# applying random instagram type filters to a bunch of photos

Tags: photoshop, instagram

I need to apply random instagram-style filters to 100 photos. It doesn't matter what filters are used, I don't need to look at each photo. It's for a christmas present photo board.

Any suggestions of photoshop script/website/any-tool-to-get-job-done?

Thanks

Comment: If printed, just throw them on the floor and walk on them. Results will invariably be superior to Instagram.

Comment: Try to use embedded javascript to Photoshop!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I make use of Photoshop plugin - [Alien Skin](http://www.alienskin.com/) with which you can  simulate the  film behavior to your image, applying filters(to simulate for example polaroid film effects). The basic Alien Skin plugin is the Exposure. You can use it either as a Photoshop plugin or separately. Moreover, there exist another similar software called [nik software](https://www.google.com/nikcollection/). As it seems it has been purchased by Google. Especially the mode Color Efex Pro (correspondigly Silver Efex Pro for bnw photography).  Personally I suggest Alien Skin. I have a feeling that instagram's filter try to mimic instant photography aesthetic. Thus the best solution is to use in Alien Skin Exposure Polaroid filters. Additionally you can try the [Polaroid software](http://poladroid.en.softonic.com/). I haven't tried it, however it seems that it could do the basic instagram effects. Edit: Photoshop comes with a module which runs javascript code. This can be located in choose File > Scripts > Browse in Photoshop. You can write your .js file in order to apply filters in a batch of photographs. You can find several command about photoshop and javascript [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1246514). Moreover, you can perform some basic tasks using the image processor script in a folder of images. This is an API for basic tasks such as some basic Photoshop filters and transformations.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use xnview. In the program there is batch convert mode where you can apply one or more filters. Here is how looks like [image: xnviewMP]

P.S. Unfortunately i do not know if its possible to apply random effect